# Keeps opening notepad when I do Server.JS in CMD

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep having this where It keeps opening the notepad of the saved file rather than outputting what I want in the command line.

I have used sublime to code and my code reads as follows:

```
Console.log("Hello World");
```

I have said that file in a folder called nodeprojects.. I have opened my CMD in the correct place, `C:\>nodeprojects\hello.js` but instead of outputting `"Hello World"` in my CMD it opens the notepad file?!

See screenshot attached.

Comment: try `node nodeprojects\hello.js`. Right now you're telling it to open that file with the default text editor but not prepending it with the node program

Comment: That gives me an error when I do that.. node is not a recognised internal or external command etc..

Comment: try `nodejs`. If that doesn't work, confirm you've installed nodejs and that the node.exe is in your PATH

Comment: I can confirm it is installed..

Comment: I have tried..   1) C:\>Nodeprojects\firstnodeproject\firstproject.js ... which opens the notepad file

Comment: Then if `node` and `nodejs` gives the same error, you don't have them in your path to be run on the commandline.

Comment: Well, when I do C:\> node Nodeprojects\firstnodeproject\firstproject.js ... I get a console is not a defined object error.

Comment: lowercase c, `console.log`

Comment: Jesus, thank you very much! What a silly mistake.

Comment: What do Assoc and ftype show you ?